# Converting Tensorboard logging files to CSV, JSON, or Dataframes

Tags: tensorflow, grafana, tensorboard, data-conversion, pytorch-lightning

My goal is to send tensorboard logging data that is already implemented to grafana for visualization.

The data is being logged with pytorch lightning's tensorboardlogger: https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/extensions/generated/lightning.pytorch.loggers.TensorBoardLogger.html

I need help converting the logged tensorboard object files into json or csv or dataframes...

I have tried converting the tensorboardlogger to pytorch lightning's CSVLogger but ended up losing a significant amount of data as well as not having access to a time. This caused the data to not be able to be graphed in a line graph as it did not have an X axis (time).

Additionally, I have tried manually downloading the tensorboard data via the visualization that comes with tensorboard.dev, but it only results in a single instance of the data rather than the entire graph.

I am hoping to have access to the data presented in the tensorboard.dev visualizations so I can send them to be visualized in Grafana. My hope is that I will be able to send the converted data to Prometheus and then Grafana (ultimately in soft-real time, and locally).

Thank you

Comment: I'm entirely sure, that I fully understand what you want, but it sounds like a task for Grafana Loki. Loki is Prometheus style log aggregator, it allows to store parsed logs and query them with prometheus-like queries.